# how to find whether object sharing common memory or different memory allocation

Tags: c#

I want to understand the behavior of below code on memory allocation perspective.

i have two List objects as shown below.

```
        var list1 = new List< string > (){ "A","B" };
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        list2 = list1;
        list1 = null;
```

When i set list1 to null, the list2 object remains as is.

But again i tried to modify the list1 object after assigning to list2, then the value of list2 changed to latest list1. i am a bit confused by this behavior.

Changed code snippet:

```
        var list1 = new List< string > (){ "A","B" };
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        list2 = list1;
        list1.Add("C");
        list1 = null;
```

In the above code, when i assigned list1 to list2, list has 2 strings but later i added one more string to list1, the same string is even added to list2. Why?

Comment: You can read list2 = list 1 as "make the list2 reference point to the same location in memory as list1", and the object that list2 did point at is marked for garbage collection, because nothing points to it. Then when you set list1 = null it means "make the list1 reference point to no allocated object"

Comment: in the second sample, both variables point to the exact same location in memory, so adding to list1 is the same as adding to list2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets pretend each `List<String>` is a house and each variable `list1` and `list2` is a peice of paper. Let me walk you though an analogy of what is happening.

The first line of code is actually doing 3 steps:

In this step you are building a house with two rooms A and B

```
           new List<string> (){ "A","B" };
```

In this step you are making a new piece of paper called "list1"

```
var list1
```

In this step you are writing the address of the house on the pecice of paper named "list1"

```
list1 = ...
```

The next line of code does the same 3 steps again

In this step you are building a house with no rooms

```
           new List<string> ();
```

In this step you are making a new piece of paper called "list2"

```
var list2
```

In this step you are writing the address of the 2nd house you built on the piece of paper named "list2"

```
list2 = ...
```

Now for the rest of the steps

In this step you take the address written on the piece of paper named "list1" and erase the address written on the piece of paper named "list2" and replace it with the address from "list1"

```
list2 = list1;
```

You drive to the address that is written on the piece of paper named "list1" (which is the same address written on the piece of paper named "list2") and build a new room named "C"

```
list1.Add("C");
```

In this step you erase the address written on the piece of paper named "list1"

```
list1 = null;
```

Hopefully with this analogy why when you modified the house (a object) who's address was written on a piece of paper (a variable) another piece of paper (another variable) with the same address written on it saw the change too.

Answer (score 0):

`list1` and `list2` have TWO same references to ONE object. When you add "C" to `list1` you change ONE object. When you set `null` to `list1` you only remove reference to ONE object, but this object still remains in memory.