# string acts like a value type

Tags: c#, string, types, reference

`string` is reference type but acts like a value type.

```
string a,b;
a=b="test"; //As i understood a and b have to point to the same location in the heap

a="a";
Console.WriteLine("a: {0}, b: {1}",a,b);
```

As result it prints **a: a, b: test**
Please explain why change made to `a` is not reflected on `b` as one can expected according to reference type rules.

Comment: I think your understanding is incorrect. `a` and `b` are their own variables, and therefore their own values. What you're thinking of is a reference type. These are value types. Also, strings are immutable meaning they when they change they change the entire thing.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with value types vs reference types. `a` and `b` are different variables so assigning to one does not affect the other.

Comment: @RichardBarker you are wrong, you will get this behavior with both reference types and value types. Also strings are not value types. Lastly, what you said about Immutable is a little ambiguous, What Immutable means is any change you make returns you a new object with the change but the original is unmodified, you must overwrite the variable with the new object if you want to use the new object.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Other than the fact that `string` is immuteable is the fact that `a="a";` is assigning a new object reference to the variable, not attempting to mutate the object that the variable points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not changing the object `a` points at, you are only changing the variable `a`. This is not something special with strings either, you can do this with any type and get the exact same behavior.

```
class Foo
{
    private int _i;

    public Foo(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _i.ToString();
    }
}

Foo a, b;
a=b= new Foo(1);

a=new Foo(2);

Console.WriteLine("a: {0}, b: {1}",a,b);
```

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998554/how-to-find-whether-object-sharing-common-memory-or-different-memory-allocation/37998693#37998693), I go in depth in an analogy of the difference between a variable and the objects they point to.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't change the value that `a` is pointing to - you changed the reference itself. This is the same as in C, for example - don't imagine that `a = "Hi"` is changing `*a`.

In fact, outside of unsafe code, there's no way to change an existing string. Strings in .NET are immutable. You only ever create new strings or change references, which means that, indeed, `string` has value semantics, like any other immutable data type. This was a design choice - strings are hard, and this makes them much simpler.

The assignment operator is not overridable in C# - it always means "assign a value to an identifier". In the case of `string`, the value is the *reference* to the string, not the string itself. But changing the reference in one local doesn't change the references in other locals. How would it? It's not a pointer to a pointer.

Let's make a better illustration of the difference between a reference type and a value type:

```
void Main()
{
  A a = default(A), b = default(A);

  a = b = new A { Number = 42 };
  a.Number = 10;

  Console.WriteLine(a); // 42
  Console.WriteLine(b); // 10
}

public struct A
{
  public int Number;
}
```

Now, A is a value-type, so when we assign `b` to `a`, we actually make a copy. The two locals do not point to the same object. So when `a.Number` is changed to 10, `b.Number` stays 42.

However, if you change the declaration to say `public class A` instead, the assignment only changes the value of the reference - in other words, only one instance of `A` exists. Then, `a.Number = 10` actually changes `b.Number` as well - the two are the same location in memory.

If you compare this to C, it's as if a value-type local was the value itself, while a reference-type local was a *pointer* to the value. So, something like this:

```
// Value-type
A a, b;

b.Number = 42;
a = b;
a.Number = 10; // Only the value in a is changed

// Reference-type
A *a, *b;

a = b = new A(42);
a->Number = 10; // Both locals point to the changed value
```

This is quite different from how C++ references work - in C#, those are limited to method arguments. So, for example, a swap method in C# would look like this:

```
void Main()
{
  int a = 42, b = 10;

  Swap(ref a, ref b);

  Console.WriteLine(a); // 10
  Console.WriteLine(b); // 42
}

public void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
  int x = 0;

  SwapI(ref a, ref b, ref x);
}

// No ref locals, so we need a helper method
private void SwapI(ref int a, ref int b, ref int x)
{
  x = a;
  a = b;
  b = x;
}
```

Since the arguments we're switching are `ref`, they always have reference semantics, regardless of whether the types are value types or reference types.

Answer (score 0):

//You intitalized the variables- Great!

string a,b;

//**a="test"** and **b="test"**
a=b="test";

//now **a="a"** and **b** is still **"test"**
a="a";

To get b to show up as "a" you have to set it as "a". The only way to set variables is to make a declaration where the variable is on the left side. So for you to make b equal to "a" you have to do something like this:
**b=a;** after your last line. So you're 3 lines would look like this:

a=b="test"; 

a="a";
//new line
b=a;

 Now when you type Console.WriteLine("a: {0}, b: {1}",a,b);

 you get  **a: a, b: a**